# 16.04 - Ubuntu Software has much less applications now. Why?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, playonlinux

I have used Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 15.10 and have had no problems installing anything via the Software Centre. However, upon changing the software center in 16.04, I am having trouble finding many things in the new 'Ubuntu Software' app; let me explain this a bit further.

In the previous versions, I could query *ubuntu-restricted-extras* and see the package and install it - such query yields no results in 16.04 but the `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` command allows me to install it.

Furthermore, other things such as Steam for playing games, google chrome, and playonlinux are no longer in the Ubuntu Software app and I am having to install them from their respective websites, most of them install fine but playonlinux is now really buggy and I never had that problem when installing from the old Software Centre.

TL;DR - Why is the new Ubuntu Software app lacking many of the applications that were in the older Ubuntu Software Centre? Is it possible to make these appear in the new app that 16.04 uses (and will they work properly if so)?

Comment: I agree with you about finding some packages: `ubuntu-restricted-extras` seems to be nowhere to be found in the new Ubuntu Software application. The old Software Center had been criticised for being slow and 'buggy' and wasn't a focus of attention for any improvements other than general maintenance, but the new Ubuntu Software will likely have a few kinks to work through for now: `sudo apt-get install` should install the same program that the Ubuntu Software would have installed, so any problems with playonlinux, for example, are more likely to do with 16.04 than Ubuntu Software itself.

Comment: So how is this even possible? It was to my understanding that the Software Center utilities like Synaptic, Ubuntu Software, and Software Centre were just GUI representation of the APT command....if so, how is it on one and not the other?

Comment: The actual program, although named Ubuntu Software is an application called Gnome Software. It has been adapted for use in Ubuntu and theoretically should be able to find any package available for Xenial Xerus and let you install it. If there are a few missing, then it is a bug that they should fix soon. You could try filing a bug report to raise awareness. I suspect that it's no easy feat to take all the available packages, categorise them and show information and reviews about each. They are adapting all that functionality to a new program & for now there might be a few bugs. It'll improve.

Comment: It would appear that it is mainly programs without a GUI that are missing from the Ubuntu Software application at the moment. Packages such as `ubuntu-restricted-extras` or other Desktop environments (Gnome, LXDE) are specific ones that seem to be missing that I remember being previously available. They're also meta-packages that install a number of programs, so perhaps it's a complication with meta-packages & non-GUI programs. It's quite possible that Gnome Software doesn't usually deal with non-GUI and meta-packages & so needs to be further adapted to include them in 'Ubuntu Software'.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue using this command:

> sudo apt-get install software-center

This will install the old version of Software center and you can Download all the required softwares .
Make sure you have a good Internet connectivity during installation .